# Series of SQL Queries Causes Server Link to Crash

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

This is a very random problem.

As of two days ago an excel spreadsheet with multiple complicated vba procedures that call various SQL commands was working perfectly.

Since then on occasion of running a large number of sequential commands (SELECTS, INSERTS and UPDATES) a crash part way through has led to the network server being accessed at the time becoming invisible to the single computer in use.

Initially it was only one computer that was having the issue, but now it appears to be a random event on every computer on the network.  I think that this is just a coincidence.

The user can log on to another computer and have full access.  Another user logs on to the affected computer and cannot access, so it is definitely a problem specific to the computer that runs the query.

Strangest of all is that the problem rectifies itself exactly 1 hour after occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the external contractors who handle the IT maintenance had installed a new virus checker on the server over the weekend.  And, after two days of insisting that it wasn't to blame, have found out that it was.  Settings changed and problem solved. :)